# Convert a string to an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like such:

```
array('some_key' => 'some_value');
```

I would like to take that and transform it to, this should be done programatically

```
array('some_key' => array('some_value'));
```

This should be rather simple to do but the only think I can find is answers on string split and explode, to explode strings into arrays. I thought PHP, like other languages, had something called `to_array` or `toArray`.

I am assuming this is super easy to do?

Comment: `$arr['some_key'] = explode('', $arr['some_key']);`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just doing the one array element, it's as simple as:

```
$newarray['some_key'] = array($sourcearray['some_key']);
```

Otherwise if your source array will have multiple entries, you can do it in a loop:

```
foreach($sourcearray AS $key => $value) {
    $newarray[$key] = array($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as `$value = array($value)` should work:

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value = array($value);
}
unset($value); //Remove the reference to the array value
```

If you prefer to do it without references:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = array($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<?php
$arr=array('some_key' => 'some_value');
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
$newarr[$k] = array($v);
}

var_dump($newarr);
```